# Apache2 serving page regardless of entered address

Tags: apache-2.2

how to configure apache2 webserver to serve pages only if request contain valid hostname/domain (one of *VirtualHost*)?
I've made some experiment, in my laptop *hosts* file I entered my server IP and some invented domain name (which doesn't exist in real, even in one of my *VirtualHost* file ie. abfgffd.com). To my suprise main apache server page displays instead of error message that this page doesn't exist.

So if somebody enter ANY hostname (directed by *hosts* file to my IP) my main webpage will appear. Strange :|

How could I prevent it? Did I miss some important apache configuration option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first defined virtual host for a given IP address is the default virtual host for that IP. So if you put something like this before your real virtual host, it will serve requests for nonexistent virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName some.random.host.name
    DocumentRoot /var/www/empty

    <Directory /var/www/empty>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Apache to use [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

EDIT: Perhaps I misunderstood. If you have a default host (defined in httpd.conf, apache2.conf, sites-available/default, etc.) then apache will use that for any domain that does not match a virtual host (defined with ServerName or ServerAlias in a `<VirtualHost>` block).

Comment: So I commented ServerName and ServerAlias from main/default config file (default VirtualHost), and now I've only files with single VirtualHosts but problem still remains.